# Meaning of "I gotta watch my figure"

Tags: expressions

Does "**I gotta watch my figure**" mean being careful not get obese?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily obese, but it does have to do with weight, yes.

When someone says they need to watch their figure, they mean they want their figure to look good, not just normal.

Many women would prefer to have a slim waist (particularly women who are inclined to say, "I need to watch my figure"). They don't want any type of "belly" if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

The word *watch* here is a verb meaning "to monitor carefully," and *figure* means the person's measurements, or silhouette. So, yes, you're on the right track. You usually hear the phrase when someone is turning down something sweet to eat; I don't think you'd be as apt to hear it if someone was, say, making a pledge to exercise more.

> Would you like a piece of cake?
> *No, thanks. I gotta watch my figure*.
>
> Want to go to the gym tomorrow?
> *That sounds great. I need to stay in shape*.

I suppose you could swap the answers to those two questions, but I've listed them in the context I'd most expect to hear them.

I also think you'll see the word "figure" used describe a woman's body more often than a man's, but I wouldn't necessarily assert the word is exclusively used in that context.